# F5 irule in a script from console

Tags: tcl, f5, irule

We've got some user data stored in LDAP that has been "encrypted" by an iRule with the AES::Encrypt function. We now find we need to use the encrypted value elsewhere.

We need to decrypt and re-encrypt it because : The Encrypt uses AES-CWC - which appears to be virtually unused anywhere else. So, we really need the F5's own code to decrypt it.

I was hoping to run a script from the console or TMOS. I can run tcl UI, but somehow need to "import" the code to do the AES functions. Is there an easy way to make a tcl session work like it does in the iRules, or a path that the iRule functions are stored in?

(And no, I can't get the F5 to provide the decrypted value to the app with an API (if there is one). The other app is querying LDAP, and can happily decode AES-CBC - but not CWC. And we can't wait for the users to login and re-encrypt with a different iRule when they do. It needs to be fixed "now"!)